# Can't get jQuery submit() to work on form created by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

So I have a tag system, and onclick, the tag button is changed into a form with one input and submit button. The problem is apparently with the fact that the form is being created AFTER the fact.

HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-success addTag">
    <a href="">+</a>
    <span class="label addTagBody">Add a skill</span>
</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.addTag').click(function() {
    $('.addTag').replaceWith('<div class="btn btn-success addTag"><form name="addTag"><input placeholder="Enter new tag" type="text" class="addTagBody"><input type="submit" value="Add"></form></div>');
});

$("form[name='addTag']").on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).serialize());
});
```

Any tips on handling scenarios like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind on(submit) event after addTag because initially the form doesn't exists.

```
$('.addTag').click(function() {
    $('.addTag').replaceWith('<div class="btn btn-success addTag"><form name="addTag"><input placeholder="Enter new tag" type="text" class="addTagBody" name="tag"><input type="submit" value="Add"></form></div>');
    $("form[name='addTag']").on('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      alert($(this).serialize());
    });
});
```

Comment: This does work! But it isn't returning anything from $(this).serialize()?

Comment: Try using $("form[name='addTag']").serialize()

Comment: Add a name for input element, that's why it doesn't appears when you call $(this).serialize()

Answer (score 2):

change your jquery part to

```
$('.addTag').click(function() {
    $('.addTag').replaceWith('<div class="btn btn-success addTag"><form name="addTag"><input placeholder="Enter new tag" type="text" class="addTagBody"><input type="submit" value="Add"></form></div>');
    $("form[name='addTag']").on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).serialize());
    });
});
```

so the form submition function is added every time the new form is created

Comment: Great, but $(this).serialize() won't return what is in my input?

Comment: add a name-Tag to your input field

Comment: Perfect. Thank you all very much.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use existing element to bind an event for elements created in the future:

```
$(document).on("submit", "form[name='addTag']", function(){ ... });
```

Also, add `name` attribute to you form's text inputs for their values to be included in serialized form.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use event delegation when you dynamically create elements.  For more information read: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form[name="addTag"]', function(){ ... });
```